# Non-global variable recognized/accepted in defined function

Tags: python, for-loop, global

I am learning and experimenting with Python and I accidentally found this very strange (to me) case. I searched as much as I could but could not find anything other than how to use global and local variables or how to use the 'for' loop. I have the following code (Python 3.2 on Android Qpython3), modified for simplicity:

```
def get_number():
    x=5**i
    print(x)
    return(x)

for i in range(1,5):
    y=get_number()
    print(y)
```

I realized that I made a mistake using the variable i in the called function as I did not define it as global. And yet, when I ran the script it worked(!) giving me the following output:

```
hon.sh "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/AK_SCRIPTS/.last_tmp.py" && exit               <
5
5
25
25
125
125
625
625

#[QPython] Press enter to exit
```

Could somebody please explain how/why the variable i is recognised within the called function and having the value it has in the calling function, even though it is not defined as global?

Comment: This code is extremely difficult to read (please use code blocks)

Answer (score 1):

Scope resolution for variable follows the LEGB rule, i.e. python tries to find a variable in the following scopes (decreasing precedence):

`Local -> Enclosed -> Global -> Built-in`

In your case, `i` is only defined in the enclosed scope.

For further details see http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2014/05/12/a-beginners-guide-to-pythons-namespaces-scope-resolution-and-the-legb-rule/

Answer (score 0):

You defined `i` in the module scope, which lets you read `i` in function scope by default. You only need to use `global i` inside `get_number` if you want to *modify* `i`.